# Ubuntu is not booting up after updating nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I updated the nvidia driver using, sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx, 'I forgot the number', then rebooted my device, not the laptop is not booting up and it shows:
thinkpad_acpi: Unknown/reserved multi mode value 0x0000 for type 4. and no cursor is showing.

ubuntu 22.04

Comment: What is the GPU? What is the driver? Probably the driver is wrong. Now you can boot in a safe mode and remove it.

Comment: how to boot into safe mode and remove it?

Comment: Safe mode is in the grub menu.

Comment: okay I boot into safe mode, how to remove the driver?

Comment: `sudo apt purge nvidia*`

Comment: that works for me thank you alot.

Comment: My second monitor is not working and I installed the new 'recommended' driver in order to work, but this happens as you saw. What to do in order for it to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142974/discussion-between-pilot6-and-sting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot in Safe Mode using grub menu and run

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```

After that you can install drivers using Software & Updates app, or `ubuntu-drivers install` command.

Make sure Secure Boot is disabled and the driver is compatible with your GPU.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the driver and install recommended Nvidia drivers.

During boot, press the ESC key to get grub settings, go to Advanced options, select recovery mode for current Kernel. In the menu you can enable networking and then drop into a root shell.

In the root shell you can run `ubuntu-drivers devices` which should identify the best Nvidia driver for your GPU. You should install the recommended Nvidia drivers from the command. These drivers will be the most compatible with your system. If you have issues installing the drivers you can purge your current drivers and then install the new drivers.

Comment: Why `acpi=off`?

Comment: I found this to help resolve some issues with Nvidia where with drivers ACPI would cause boot errors. It is a recommendation because of the error being very similar to ones I faced.

Comment: It is NOT recommended!

Comment: How come? It doesn't seem to cause and issues with it turned off. It was the only method I found the help.

Comment: You could have some other specific problem. It is not recommended to do just in case.

Comment: Ok I will remove from my answer. We do run it on older versions of Ubuntu, but I assumed it could still apply to more updated versions.